# How to inject an IServiceScope into a class in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a problem with injecting `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScope` into my class.

My service implementation:

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceScope _services;

    public AccountService(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IServiceScope services) // <-- I can't inject this
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _services = services;
    }
    
    public async Task CreateAccount(ExternalAccount externalAccount)
    {
        (some code...)
    }
}
```

In startup.cs:

```
services.AddTransient<IAccountService, AccountService>();
```

The problem is that project crashes after above line with following error:

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IDS.Quickstart.Account.IAccountService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IDS.Quickstart.Account.AccountService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScope' while attempting to activate 'IDS.Quickstart.Account.AccountService'.)
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IDS.Quickstart.Account.IAccountService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: IDS.Quickstart.Account.AccountService': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceScope' while attempting to activate 'IDS.Quickstart.Account.AccountService'.

What is the reason my code refuses to work?

Comment: Inject IServiceScopeFactory and use that to create IServiceScope

Comment: This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yep, injected IServiceScopeFactory works. You can answer my question I upvote it. Some explanation why IServiceScope cannot be injected will be nice.

Comment: Even if `IServiceScopeFactory` works I'd try not to inject it. Does your class really need that? Almost certainly not. It needs something that it wants to resolve. I'd try to inject that. Or, if necessary, a more specific factory that produces exactly the type you need. If you inject a DI component that's usually the service locator anti-pattern. It makes code harder to understand and harder to test.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of injecting an `IServiceScope`, with MS.DI you inject an `IServiceProvider`. MS.DI will automatically inject a version of the `IServiceProvider` that is scoped to the current scope. This means that your class can call `IServiceProvider.GetService` which will lead to the same results as what would happen when you call `IServiceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService`.

Please be careful with the injection of container-specific abstractions such as `IServiceProvider`, `IServiceScopeFactory`, or `IServiceScope`. If injected into classes that live outside your [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/), it leads to the [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/). Service Locator comes with quite a few downsides. The name of your class, `AccountService`, makes me believe that this class lives outside your Composition Root.

Classes that live inside the Composition Root typically consist of solely infrastructure logic (no business logic). Within the Composition Root it is fine to have a dependency on the DI Container (or its abstractions) because this part of the already has a very strong dependency on that particular DI Container.

So if you can, extract the logic that requires to resolve instances from the `AccountService` class, and move that into a class that consists of solely infrastructure logic, and place it inside the Composition Root.